# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, support

I flagged [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/hi-im-very-new-to-this-and-im-wondering-if-tor-is-what-i-need-to-solve-ip-proble) question as *unclear what you're asking*, but it was declined.

But one of the moderator Andrew Lott has clearly mentioned in his comment yesterday "Please edit your question to clarify what you mean. As it stands it's unclear what you're asking and may be closed."

May I know why my flag was declined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, sorry! I meant to just add the comment and skip over the flag until this user had a chance to edit their question, but I seem to have declined it in the process by mistake :(

If you can re-flag it, then I'll accept it to close the question.

Comment: No problems ;) Was just wondering! I have flagged it for moderator intervention.

Comment: And...... done!